# Interaction isn't translating input Text to Strings

Tags: actionscript-3, text, input, actionscript

I'm in need of some help. To start with, what I have is an interaction where you fill out 5 text boxes in response to 2 questions. Each of the 5 answers must be filled out as input text and then checked against an array of acceptable responses when the done button is clicked. Also, there are two type differences in the fields. So the first three answer fields belong to a range of acceptable responses in the array: Type A and the next two questions to Type B. It's possible to fill out the correct responses in any order, so long as the typing is correct.

What I can't seem to figure out is why the textFields aren't translating to Strings.

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();


//*--------------------------------------------
//
//                  THINGS YOU CAN CHANGE
//
//*--------------------------------------------

var a_inputType:Array = new Array("Doggie Day Spa", "Deb's Dog Walking Service", "Pet Market", "Pampered Pet", "TLC Grooming");     //All recognized type responses, Type A listed before Type B
var n_typeA:Number = new Number(3);                                                                                                 //Sets the range for Type A


//*--------------------------------------------
//
//                  PAGE SETUP
//
//*--------------------------------------------

var n_typeB:Number = new Number(a_inputType.length - n_typeA +1);       //Finds the range of Type B
var a_testArray:Array = new Array();                                    //Holds push data from submit button

var a_correctArray:Array = new Array();                                 //Creates an array to run a final test against
for(var c = 0; c<=a_inputType.length-1; c++){                           //Loop populates the array
    a_correctArray.push(1);
}

var inputField1:TextField = new TextField();                            //Creates the Text Fields
var inputField2:TextField = new TextField();
var inputField3:TextField = new TextField();
var inputField4:TextField = new TextField();
var inputField5:TextField = new TextField();

var txtString1:String = new String();                                   //Creates the strings for translating the input text
var txtString2:String = new String();
var txtString3:String = new String();
var txtString4:String = new String();
var txtString5:String = new String();

for(var f = 1; f<=a_inputType.length; f++){                             //Assigns them properties, locations, and adds a listener for text
    var fieldBuilder = "inputField"+f;
    var fieldFinder = "txt_pos"+f;
    addChild(this[fieldBuilder]);
    this[fieldBuilder].border = false;
    this[fieldBuilder].width = 290;
    this[fieldBuilder].height = 25;
    this[fieldBuilder].x = this[fieldFinder].x;
    this[fieldBuilder].y = this[fieldFinder].y;
    this[fieldBuilder].type = "input";
    this[fieldBuilder].multiline = true;
    this[fieldBuilder].text = "";
    this[fieldBuilder].addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, function (){
                             var stringBuilder = "txtString"+f;
                             this[stringBuilder] = this[fieldBuilder].text;
                             });
}


//*--------------------------------------------
//
//                  FUNCTIONS
//
//*--------------------------------------------

function SUBMIT(event:MouseEvent):void{                                 
    for(var t=1; t<=a_inputType.length; t++){                           //Loop establishes checks for each String against an input type
        if(t<=n_typeA){                                                 //if/else divides the textfields into two ranges: typeA and typeB
            checkTypeA(this["txtString"+t], a_inputType);               //sends the array of correct responses and the captured String to checkTypeA
        }else{
            checkTypeB(this["txtString"+t], a_inputType);               //sends the array of correct responses and the captured String to checkTypeB
        }
    }
    var TEMPSELECT = a_testArray.toString();                            //reduces the testArray recieving push data into a String
    var TEMPCORRECT = a_correctArray.toString();                        //reduces the correctArray from scene set-up into a String
    if(TEMPSELECT == TEMPCORRECT){                                      //compares the strings and determines a trace response
        trace("correct");
    }else{
        trace("incorrect");
    }
}

function checkTypeA(value:String, arr:Array){                           //Checks the String against all the array values within the specified range for type A
    for (var a=1; a<=n_typeA; a++){                                     //determines the range
        if (arr[a]==value){                                             //checks the value
            a_testArray.push(1);                                        //if true, generates a push value for a testArray to be checked later
        }
    }
}

function checkTypeB(value:String, arr:Array){                           
    for (var b = n_typeA; b<=n_typeB; b++){
        if (arr[b-1]==value){
            a_testArray.push(1);
        }
    }
}


//*--------------------------------------------
//
//                  BUTTONS
//
//*--------------------------------------------

done_bttn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SUBMIT);                   //Launches the SUBMIT function when "Done" is pressed.
```

Upon further investigation I've noticed that the loop isn't terminating when it reaches 5. It keeps regurgitating TextFields over and over again with the same variable names and instancing. Because of this, the addChild is dumping input fields one on top of one another in the flash file (which makes editing a text field impossible since your always clicking on a new field positioned directly on top of the one you just edited).

The trace on the loop comes back like this:

```
inputField1
txt_pos1
inputField2
txt_pos2
inputField3
txt_pos3
inputField4
txt_pos4
inputField5
txt_pos5
inputField1
txt_pos1
inputField2
txt_pos2
inputField3
txt_pos3
inputField4
txt_pos4
inputField5
txt_pos5
inputField1
txt_pos1
inputField2
txt_pos2
```

and so on.... how can I stop this looping behavior. I've tried if/else breaking and that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The context of the `this` keyword changes when you call it from a local function. You can easily verify it if you add `trace(this)` to your anonymous function. It will trace out `[object global]`.  Two solutions come to mind, store a reference of `this` in a variable:

```
var self:MovieClip = this;
for(var f = 1; f<=a_inputType.length; f++){      
    //...
    this[fieldBuilder].addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, function (){
                             var stringBuilder = "txtString"+f;
                             self[stringBuilder] = self[fieldBuilder].text;
                             });
}
```

Or declare a new function:

```
for(var f = 1; f<=a_inputType.length; f++){      
    //...
    this[fieldBuilder].addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, myFunction);
}

function myFunction(t:TextEvent){
                         var stringBuilder = "txtString"+f;
                         this[stringBuilder] = (t.target as TextField).text;
}
```

Comment: This change isn't altering the returns I'm getting at all. The trace for the TextField is still blank.

Comment: is your movieclip continuously looping despite the `stop();` in the beginning?

Comment: As it turns out it was a corruption in the flash file itself. I copied out to a fresh file and it all works now.